# How does github lets you navigate pages without refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've navigated a lot through the github website. I've observed that whenever I click on a link, the page does not refresh and even the URL in the browser is changed. Moreover, those links are added in the history!

Well, I know that AJAX is a way to go and I know a lot of JavaScript(semi-intermediate level coder) but you can't change the URL with Ajax. Neither can you make those URLs be visible in the history.

So, how the heck do they do it?

Comment: [MDN - Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of tools out there to make this process easy nowadays, check out [HistoryJS](http://balupton.github.io/history.js/demo/) and [NavJS](http://widgetulous.com/navjs/).

Microsoft released an example application harnessing these technologies a while ago named "Big Shelf", which seems to have been taken down unfortunately. Obviously that's only relevant if you're using .NET.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question of how it's done. It just moves the question from github to those libraries.

Comment: True, I guess, but I know if I asked the question in this scenario, I'd like to know the tools out there in order to achieve what I want to do.

Comment: [Great Tut on HTML 5 Hisotry API](http://html5doctor.com/history-api/)